# Styling a singel cell in Java+ CSS

Tags: javascript, java, css

Is possible to implement this solution using Java and not javascript?

```js
const percent = 6.9

document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundImage = 
  `linear-gradient(to right, red, red  ${percent}%, white ${100 - percent}%)`
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="special"></div>
```

Comment: Well, generally having a bit of code to understand what the problem is helps.

Comment: i don't have code because i need how is it done,, why do you need the code, the dinamic value is a value that i get from how days a worker work at a month,
i days/month*100

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, red  68.9%, white 31.1%);` in your cell.

Here is a quick example (static): http://jsfiddle.net/7dfq8vcy/

Hope this help :)

PS: and of course you can do it dynamically http://jsfiddle.net/8rz6vpdL/

Comment: Thanks to my friend but this is static and i know that the problem is the value is different every time isn't always 68.9 is a dynamic value/.

Comment: Check the new example above ;) you can update it every time you want to

Comment: @gengs do you know java, is it possible to do it with java and not with javascript?? anyway that is very helpful, but if i can be done with java  that will be great

Comment: @Xenis here is an easier syntax where you simply need to adjust background-size: http://jsfiddle.net/tkxr7pgu/

Comment: @TemaniAfif  -gengns has solved a dynamic one the second example.. i just need to know is this possible in java.But thank you a lot

Comment: @Xenis I know, I simply provided another way where you don't need the white color and where you need to modify only one value.

Comment: @TemaniAfif the value for example 60 i get it in a dinamic way, look at the second example at you see the value is a constant...the value depends it can be 40,50,60 or whatever i don't know, but as you try to help, thank you so much

Comment: @Xenis you can easily change it :http://jsfiddle.net/1cqe7Lnj/ I simply gave an example of syntax that you can easily make dynamic

Comment: Can i ask you sth is possible using to values  for example 20 and let some space and continue at 60 if this would work will be great......@TemaniAfif in a dynamic way will be great.

Comment: Can i ask you sth is possible using to values  for example 20 and let some space and continue at 60 if this would work will be great......@gengns in the dinamic way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187107/discussion-between-xenis-and-temani-afif).